# python pydantic How to choose class based on another value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

some of example of schema . I have different constraints based on type

```
short_text = {
    "text": "Some question goes here ",
    "description": "Some descritpion goes here ",
    "type": "short_text",
    "constraints": {
        "max_chars": -1,
        "required": True
    }
}

multiple_choice = {
    "text": "Some question goes here ",
    "description": "Some descritpion goes here ",
    "type": "multiple_choice",
    "constraints": {
        "multiple_selection": True,
        "required": True,
        "randomized": True,
        "other_option": True
    },
    "items": [
        {1: "choice 1"}, {2: "choice 2"}, {3: "choice 3"}
    ]
}

social_media = {
    "text": "Some question goes here ",
    "description": "Some descritpion goes here ",
    "type": "social_media",
    "constraints": {
        "platforms": [
            {
                "platform": "facebook",
                "required": True
            }, {
                "platform": "instagram",
                "required": True
            }, {
                "platform": "twitter",
                "required": True
            }, {
                "platform": "tiktok",
                "required": True
            }, {
                "platform": "snapchat",
                "required": True
            }
        ]
    }
}

multiple_choice = {
    "text": "Some question goes here ",
    "description": "Some descritpion goes here",
    "type": "multiple_choice",
    "constraints": {
        "multiple_selection": True,
        "required": True,
        "randomized": True,
        "other_option": True
    },
    "items": [
        {1: "choice 1"}, {2: "choice 2"}, {3: "choice 3"}
    ]
}
```

i write this

```
from __future__ import annotations

from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union, Literal, Optional, List


# =============================== ShortText type questions =============
class ShortTextConstraints(BaseModel):
    max_chars: int
    required: bool


# =============================== multiple_choice type questions =============

class MultipleChoiceConstraints(BaseModel):
    multiple_selection: bool
    required: bool
    randomized: bool
    other_option: bool


# =============================== yes_no type questions =============
# =============================== email type questions =============

class YesNoConstraints(BaseModel):
    required: bool


# =============================== number type questions =============
class NumberConstraints(BaseModel):
    required: bool
    min_number: ValidateNumber
    max_number: ValidateNumber


class ValidateNumber(BaseModel):
    checked: bool
    value: int


# =============================== phone_number type questions =============
class PhoneNumberConstraints(BaseModel):
    required: bool
    default_country_code: str


# =============================== phone_number type questions =============
class DropdownConstraints(BaseModel):
    required: bool
    randomaize: bool
    alpabetical_order: bool


# =============================== social_media type questions =============
class SocialMediaConstraints(BaseModel):
    platforms: List[ValidatePlatforms]


class ValidatePlatforms(BaseModel):
    platform: str
    required: bool


class QuestionBase(BaseModel):
    text: str
    description: str
    type: str
    constraints: SocialMediaConstraints
    items: Optional[List[dict]]


QuestionBase.update_forward_refs()
NumberConstraints.update_forward_refs()
SocialMediaConstraints.update_forward_refs()
```

but in this line

```
  constraints: SocialMediaConstraints
```

automatically based on type for example

if type is short_text use ShortTextConstraints

else if type is multiple_choice use MultipleChoiceConstraints

else if type is social_media use SocialMediaConstraints

i try union for example but not work fine

Comment: What's wrong with Union?

Comment: i can't handle this based on type  @sudden_appearance

Comment: `QuestionBase.parse_obj(short_text)` works fine with `constraints: Union[SocialMediaConstraints, ShortTextConstraints, MultipleChoiceConstraints,]`, don't know what do you actually want)

Comment: problem in Union when some values have issue appear validate for all class not one class @sudden_appearance

Comment: for example `data = QuestionBase(**social_media)` and change some values appear all values for all classes